# Como obter as propriedades das colunas de uma tabela?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou trabalhando com uma tabela criada por outra pessoa, e existe nela um campo de `CPF`, gostaria de saber qual é o tamanho desse campo, quantos caracteres ele é capaz de suportar.

Sei que no SQL-Server, na parte de query, existe um comando para esse fim, pois já até fiz, mas não estou encontrando.

Comment: Sobre "_quantos caracteres ele é capaz de suportar_", depende de como foi declarado. Você está utilizando o Management Studio para montar o código da _query_?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a parte do "*quantos caracteres ele é capaz de suportar*", você se refere a quantidade de caracteres  que a coluna vai armazenar enviado no `value` no momento do `insert`?

Comment: Sim, estou usando o Management Studio.

Comment: Me referi ao tamanho do campo mesmo, @AndréFilipe .

Comment: Ah, entendi Leonardo. Neste caso depende de quanto o atributo `LENGTH` retornar, a quantidade de caracteres não pode ultrapassar esse valor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu utilizo `sp_help`, que obtém informação de toda a tabela

```
sp_help NomeTabela
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-help-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: De longe a melhor alternativa.

Comment: Esse tinha sido o comando que eu tinha visto antes e é a melhor alternativa nesse caso, estava buscando o atalho do teclado para esse, você sabe qual seria?

Comment: O @Matheus, em uma outra resposta deu o atalho: `ALT + F1`

Comment: Quando você disse que tinha visto o comando imaginei que fosse esse mesmo, que bom que deu certo, eu também não sabia do atalho kk

Comment: Seria legal você testar as outras opções também, retornar um feedback, e se funcionar dar um voto a favor, pessoal gastou um tempo escrevendo uma resposta para te ajudar

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o comando

`exec sp_help nomeTabela`

ou simplesmente utilizar o atalho alt + F1 que já é default do SQL no nome da sua tabela.

Comment: Para melhorar o conteúdo de sua resposta, você poderia explicar ao autor da pergunta o que esse comando `exec` faz.

Comment: Sua resposta acrescentou o atalho que eu precisava, mas não foi nem a mais abrangente nem a mais direta, mesmo assim, me ajudou muito!

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas !

Answer (score 1):

> "gostaria de saber qual é o tamanho desse campo"

você pode usar a propriedade `COL_LENGTH` que recebe dois parâmetros obrigatórios. 
O primeiro é a tabela que você deseja verificar e o segundo é a coluna que deseja saber o valor do lenght definido na execução `DDL`.

No seu caso, basta realizar a seguinte instrução:

```
SELECT COL_LENGTH('nome_da_tabela', 'CPF') AS TAMANHO_CPF;
```

Fonte: [docs.microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/col-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: A resposta que eu encontrei, atende de maneira mais ampla e analisa a tabela como um todo. Mas a sua resposta é obviamente a resposta mais simples e direta para a pergunta que eu fiz!

Comment: Obrigado @LeonardoR.Oliveira, fico feliz em poder ajudá-lo!

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a tabela [`COLUMNS`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) do `information_schema`:

```
SELECT column_name,
       data_type,
       character_maximum_length
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_name = 'tabela'
   AND column_name = 'coluna';
```

---

> [`COLUMNS`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> Retorna uma linha para cada coluna que pode ser acessada pelo usuário atual no banco de dados atual.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> | Nome da coluna           | Tipo de dados   | Descrição
>
> ...
>
> | DATA_TYPE                | nvarchar( 128 ) | Tipo de dados fornecido pelo sistema.
>
> ...
>
> | CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH | int             | Comprimento máximo, em caracteres, de dados binários, dados de caracteres e dados de texto e imagem.
> ```

Comment: Por algum motivo, essa query retornou `null` no tamanho da coluna, não resolveu para mim, você saberia o motivo de ter retornado `null`?

Comment: @LeonardoR.Oliveira o que retornou null? alguma coluna? ou não teve resultado algum, nenhuma linha?

Comment: A coluna `character_maximum_length` retornou `null` o restante está ok.

Comment: @LeonardoR.Oliveira boa pergunta. Qual o tipo da coluna? `VARCHAR`?

Comment: O tipo dessa coluna é `bigint`

Comment: É por isso que não funciona?

Comment: @LeonardoR.Oliveira sim, achei que era `VARCHAR` (o que normalmente seria o correto). O `BIGINT` tem um rage de -2^63 (-9.223.372.036.854.775.808) a 2^63-1 (9.223.372.036.854.775.807)

Comment: Sim, @Sorack , mas como eu coloquei na pergunta, não sei nem quem criou essa tabela, e ainda vou pegar muita coisa desse jeito kkk
De qualquer forma agradeço!

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei a resposta em um post no Stack Overflow em inglês, segue o código da resposta:

```
SELECT 
    c.name 'Column Name',
    t.Name 'Data type',
    c.max_length 'Max Length',
    c.precision ,
    c.scale ,
    c.is_nullable,
    ISNULL(i.is_primary_key, 0) 'Primary Key'
FROM    
    sys.columns c
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
WHERE
    c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('YourTableName')
```

Basta substituir `'YourTableName'` com o nome da tabela que você deseja analisar.

Funciona do SQL-Server 2005 pra cima!

O link para o post original é:

[Resposta - Em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418527/sql-server-query-to-get-the-list-of-columns-in-a-table-along-with-data-types-no)

Answer (score 1):

Além dessas formas citadas acima, existe outra maneira bem simples.
Basta selecionar o nome da tabela no Editor do SSMS(SQL Server Management Studio) e pressionar ALT + F1.

Isso vai te possibilitar de ver as propriedades da tabela em questão, como, quais são as colunas, tipos de dados,constraints, etc...

Comment: Um dos comentários acima trouxe essa mesma opção, mas de qualquer forma, ela funciona.